# How to authorize an app to access my account data when no auth popup shows (as a regular FB user, not app developer)?

Tags: facebook, popup, authorization

This question comes from a NON-DEVELOPER. The APP is not mine, I just need it running correctly. I need to authorize this application http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=326971544008818 to access my account (otherwise it's not working properly) but it's opening directly without asking me if I wan't to authorize it or not. How do I get to the authorization popup?

Thanks much!!

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation on authorizing users](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#web_server_auth) and getting an access token is what you need.

Comment: Yes, it does require permission. If anyone knows how to get to that dialog I would be grateful. Cheers!!